How to connect a trivial receiver to the sender returned by unifex::type_erased_stream?
For some reason type_erased_stream seems to want to ask the receiver about the scheduler (why?), but I'm unable to make the receiver reply.
Here's the code in question.
#include <unifex/receiver_concepts.hpp>
#include <unifex/scheduler_concepts.hpp>
#include <unifex/type_erased_stream.hpp>
#include <unifex/just.hpp>
#include <unifex/just_done.hpp>

using namespace unifex;

struct R
{
    template <class... Args>
    void set_value(Args&&... args) && noexcept {}
    void set_error(std::exception_ptr e) && noexcept {}
    void set_done() && noexcept {}

    friend auto tag_invoke(tag_t<get_scheduler>) noexcept
    {
        return current_scheduler;
    }
};

struct S
{
    friend auto tag_invoke(tag_t<next>, S& s) noexcept
    {
        return just(42);
    }

    friend auto tag_invoke(tag_t<cleanup>, S&) noexcept
    {
        return just_done();
    }
};

int main()
{
    //auto j = just(42);
    //auto c = connect(j, R{});
    //c.start();

    auto s = type_erase<int>(S{});
    auto c = connect(next(s), R{});
    c.start();
}

